# Extract controls from screenshots

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, mac, windows, screenshot

Is there a tool that can extract controls from screenshots (dialogues, windows,...) automatically in something like layers in Photoshop?
In my memory there was a tool for Mac doing this. But I couldn't find it anymore. Better would be such a tool for windows, of course ;-)

Comment: well snagit and some com scripting can go a long way. theoretically this is possible but we have passed the point where progs use win32api so not all apps can be scraped with high efficency as their gui drawing may be custom. so for example fetching menuitems from notepad and mathematica no problem fetching from chrome or firefox... problem. So back in 98 no problems, modern qt a bit problematic

Answer (score 1):

[Layers](http://wuonm.com/layers.html) does what you ask on the Mac.

Takes a screenshot, but creates layers for all elements - windows, shadows, cursors, etc.

Comment: Ah ok ... thanks ... seems to be down and not supported anymore.